# NodeJS MYSQL Query result Buffer?

Tags: mysql, node.js, buffer

mysql select query result ...

```
//nodejs database.js
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'me',
    database : 'test',
    password : '1234'
});

// nodejs app.js
app.get('/api/v0.1/getPostList', function(req, res) {
        limit_count = 5;
        db.query(postModel.postList(limit_count) , function(err, rows) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(rows)
            res.json(rows);
        });
    });

//result
RowDataPacket {
    POST_SEQ: 13,
    POST_TYPE: <Buffer 31 31 30 30>,
    CATEGORY: <Buffer 49 54 20 2f 20 4d 4f 42 49 4c 45>, ...
```

---

why query data buffer type?
I do not know the cause.

java query data success

[DEBUG][2016-10-28 19:20:24,160] <== Row: 13, 1100, GAME ...

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue with int values generated by COUNT. I was able to resolve the issue by casting these values to CHAR within my query.  They then came back correctly formatted as js strings.  Here's a sample query:

```
SELECT Date, Park, COUNT(FileID) FROM SkatePix WHERE Park != '' AND Date != 0 GROUP BY Date, Park LIMIT 5;
```

I changed the COUNT statement to be:

```
 CAST(COUNT(FileID) AS CHAR) /* formerly COUNT(FileID) */
```

This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by accessing values:

rows[0].POST_TYPE.toString('utf8');
   rows[0].CATEGORY.toString('utf8');

Answer (score 1):

but this would cause performance issue if you are having a lot of records and fields. You would have to iterate and tostring all buffer fields.
It should receive data in the predefined datatypes. ie VARCHAR -> String

Answer (score 1):

This topic is very old.

However, I do not have a good answer anywhere.

I found good solution. So I reply this topic

> reference (npm - mysql)
>   https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#type-casting

```html
// Modify the typeCast option to suit your situation.
createConnection({
    host: config.host,
    port: config.port,
    user: config.user,
    password: config.password,
    database: config.database,
    multipleStatements: true,
    typeCast: function (field, next) {
        if (field.type == 'VAR_STRING') {
            return field.string();
        }
        return next();
    }
})
```